# AVRdude: AVR Part "ATmega16A" not found

Tags: avrdude

I'm trying to write my first program to ATmega16A but I have an error:

> **avrdude: AVR Part "atmega16a" not found.**

But actually I've changed the chip with a similar ATmega16A and I'm sure that the chip is powered by measuring the voltage on the IC **GND** and **Vcc** pins; power is driven from the AVR pocket prog (I bought one a programmer like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825)) and I'm trying to apply what is described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfQBS22jxL8). The only difference that I'm using ATmega16A; is there any solution for such thing?

```
#include<avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
   DDRB = 0b00000001;
   PORTB = 0b00000001;
   while(1)
   {
   }

   return 0 ;
}
```

[image: avrdude screenshot]

Comment: I just have the same problem, did you resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolásAgustínBarretoValent  Well I found that the pocketprog doesn't support the atmega16 but you can use other target microcontrollers.

Answer (score 5):

The ATmega16A is a [*revision*](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8163.pdf) of the ATmega16. According to the [AVRdude documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html), the part number for the ATmega16 is "m16" (but you can also use the full part name).

Try `atmega16` or `m16` and leave off the "a".